# The life cycle of Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I asked a question about Fragment's initialization and post my code( [Delay initialization when using Fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580369/delay-initialization-when-using-fragment-in-android) ). The question is solved. But my problem still exists. When I call `onLoad()` to get the variables, it throws `NullPointerException`. I initialize these variables in `onCreateView()`. So I guess the life cycle is end. I loged the info in A.java in these function: `onDestroy`, `onDestroyView`, `onStop`. the `onDestroyView` and `onStop` is called while the `onDestroy` is not when fragment A is changed to another one. Strange:

There is a EditText in fragment A. I input a string `abc`. 1、If the life cycle is end, then when I change fragment from A to another then change back to A, the input should be empty. But it's NOT. 2、if the life cycle is not end, why can't I get the variable?

So is there anything to save the `abc` somewhere? What's it? Where?

It seems that I can't delay the initialization in Fragment. I can't get the non-static variables.

```
Code:
/** super class of Fragment */
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onLoad(Context context){
    }
}

/** */
public class AFragment extends BaseFragment{
    TextView name;
    @Override
    public View onCreateVew(...){
        name = new TextView(..);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoad(Context context){
         // here will throw NullPointerException
         name.setText("=========");
    }
}


public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener,ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    ....
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.mClss.getName(), info.mArgs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);

        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);

        BaseFragment f = (BaseFragment) getItem(position);
        f.onLoad(mContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace where you are getting the `NullPointerException` along with the code?

Comment: @antew done! you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

> But my problem still exists. When I call onLoad() to get the
>   variables, it throws NullPointerException. I initialize these
>   variables in onCreateView().

The problem is in the way you work with those fragments. More exactly, in the `onPageSelected` method you call the `FragmentPagerAdapter`'s `getItem()` method to find the fragment for that position(or this is what I'm thinking you're trying to do). But calling this method simply **instantiate a new fragment** each time you call it, it doesn't give you a reference to the `ViewPager`'s fragment for that position. This newly instantiated fragment isn't attached to an `Activity` and it's `onCreateView` method hasn't be called so it doesn't have any views created. Attempting to use your `onLoad` method to access one of this views is wrong and it will throw that `NullPointerException`. You should try to use my code from the previous answer, as that code will try to find the fragments that the `ViewPager` instantiated and it's using as its pages through the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: I also have this problem with "vanishing" variables, and even the getactivity() returns null. But I am NOT calling getItem more than once for each TAB in the viewPager, since that would have replaced the fragment instance as correctly pointed out by Luksprog. So therefore the question is this: How come the fragment instance still looses it variabel set, because, seemingly, a new fragment instance has "taken over" the tab ? Is it something internally in the viewPager/FragmentPagerAdapter that causes this?

Comment: Sorry, my question posed earlier today on getActivty that returns null and is probably subject to the same syndrome, is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245048/in-the-actionbartabspager-tutorial-getactivity-returns-null